# Keras : is it possible to give lamda layer a name?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I have following code inside my model definition

```
# (None, 6) -> (None, 8)
def affine_to_projective(x):
    y = tf.pad(x,
               paddings=tf.constant([[0, 0], [0, 2]]),
               mode='CONSTANT',
               constant_values=0
               )
    return y

projective_transform = Lambda(affine_to_projective)(affine_transform)
```

In model summary it's seen as

```
lambda_1 (Lambda)               (None, 8)            0           affine_transform[0][0]
```

Is it possible to give this layer a name instead of `lambda_1`?

Comment: Yes, did you try to give it a name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
projective_transform = Lambda(affine_to_projective, name='lambda_name')(affine_transform)
```